How is a string extracted ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> from structure
I have the follwing structure that comes in a callback. I recieve it in our callback fine:
/// Provides information about the occurred event.
final class idevice_event_t extends ffi.Struct {
  /// < The event type.
  @ffi.UnsignedInt()
  external int event;

  /// < The device unique id.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> udid;

  /// < The connection type.
  @ffi.UnsignedInt()
  external int conn_type;
}

 void onDeviceChanged(Pointer<idevice_event_t> device, Pointer<Void> data) {
    idevice_event_t event = device.ref;

    log(event.udid.cast<Utf8>().toDartString());
  }

However when i try to parse this i get an error about a bad/missing delmiter. In c this is just a normal ascii string. It appears that its parsing the address not the pointer it is refrencing. Any ideas?
I have tried looking a the memory in C and it appears ok. The struct decodes just fine in C. I there an issue with an open length string like this?

toDartString takes an optional length if you know that - but seems like not. With no length, it scans the chars looking for a null - see https://pub.dev/documentation/ffi/latest/ffi/Utf8Pointer/toDartString.html - particularly the bit where it calls _length. In Dart, try printing the first char, second char, etc - do those look correct. If you keep going, do you see all the chars, followed by a null - or some other error first? Try looking at the implementation of _length in extension Utf8Pointer.

There characters don't look right. They look like the address to the string. Not the actual string.

How did you generate the Struct? What does the C header for that look like? Is it actually a pointer to pointer to char?

I used ffgen. The c header is typedef struct {  enum idevice_event_type event; /**< The event type. */  const char *udid; /**< The device unique id. */  enum idevice_connection_type conn_type; /**< The connection type. */ } idevice_event_t;

You can test if it's the address by comparing it with event.udid.address

But if parse the data that its pointing its the address value not the string. But if i use a pointer to a pointer that doesn't work either. When you look at this in C in the debugger that value is a pointer to address. I don't know if ffi is expecting an array of character's right after the event type and not a pointer to another location. But if you walk the values as an Uint8 array thats what you get.

The data was being deleted before the microtask was called. Fixed by creating a wrapper that allocates and copies the data.
